# NoMethodError in Admin - Rails change of namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is really bugging me. My controller was working fine, but I have now changed the namespace and appear to be having issues with the paths or something. I tried editing the paths in accordance with rake routes but still no avail

here is the error:

```
Showing /home/will/Development/Ruby-Files/tasks/app/views/admin/testos/index.html.erb  where line #16 raised:

undefined method `testo_path' for #<#<Class:0xb61ee4f0>:0xaeb2c38>
```

My controller:

```
class Admin::TestosController < ApplicationController
  # GET /testos
  # GET /testos.json
  def index
    @testos = Testo.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @testos }
    end
  end

  # GET /testos/1
  # GET /testos/1.json
  def show
    @testo = Testo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @testo }
    end
  end

  # GET /testos/new
  # GET /testos/new.json
  def new
    @testo = Testo.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @testo }
    end
  end

  # GET /testos/1/edit
  def edit
    @testo = Testo.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /testos
  # POST /testos.json
  def create
    @testo = Testo.new(params[:testo])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @testo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @testo, notice: 'Testo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @testo, status: :created, location: @testo }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @testo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /testos/1
  # PUT /testos/1.json
  def update
    @testo = Testo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @testo.update_attributes(params[:testo])
        format.html { redirect_to @testo, notice: 'Testo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @testo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /testos/1
  # DELETE /testos/1.json
  def destroy
    @testo = Testo.find(params[:id])
    @testo.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to testos_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

And my view file

## Listing testos

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Entry</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @testos.each do |testo| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= testo.title %></td>
    <td><%= testo.entry %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', testo %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_testo_path(testo) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', testo, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Testo', new_testo_path %>
```

My routing:

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :testos
end
```

Rake routes:

```
        root        /                                Pages#index
        admin_testos GET    /admin/testos(.:format)          admin/testos#index
                     POST   /admin/testos(.:format)          admin/testos#create
     new_admin_testo GET    /admin/testos/new(.:format)      admin/testos#new
    edit_admin_testo GET    /admin/testos/:id/edit(.:format) admin/testos#edit
         admin_testo GET    /admin/testos/:id(.:format)      admin/testos#show
                     PUT    /admin/testos/:id(.:format)      admin/testos#update
                     DELETE /admin/testos/:id(.:format)      admin/testos#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view contains non-namespaced routes. Substitute these out for namespaced ones:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', admin_testo_path(testo) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_testo_path(testo) %></td>
```

Comment: I do think I tried that, ill give it a go now though to double check

Comment: this is the error I get:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/testos"}`

Comment: sorry I apologise I did not include the bracket, could you explain why I have to add path and (testo) and I can't just add admin_ ?

Comment: also `   <%= link_to 'New Testo', new_admin_testo_path %>` works but is not consistent with the others - as in if I add (testo) an error is produced. the inconsistency is so confusing hmm

Comment: In views, routes are connoted by appending `_path` to the route name. You were formerly using `testo` as your path, which works because, by default, Rails knows to map a single model object to its respective `show` action. But `admin_testo` is _not_ a model object - it's a route. So you need to specifically declare that it's a route by appending `_path` to the end of it.

Comment: The reason `<%= link_to 'New Testo', new_admin_testo_path(testo) %>` produces an error is that you're passing an existing instance of `testo` to a `new` action, when in fact you should be instantiating a new model object entirely. Because there's no need to pass an existing model object (as you have tried) to the route, Rails will produce an error.

Comment: Passing something in parentheses to a route is how you pass _anything_ to the action that is routed to. In this case, you are passing in an instance of `testo`, which is what you want your controller action to operate on.